# TransactionScope, when to use and potential overheads?

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactionscope

I am well familiar with Transactions and what they are designed to achieve however when working with a large, multi-user system I can't seem to find a lot of guidance on when they should be employed and the potential overheads.

It is my understanding that when you execute a SqlCommand and you do no specify a Transaction that Sql Server will implicitly create a transation. So I assume that if I did explicitly create a Transaction (with the same IsolationLevel as what is default) then there would be no added overhead.

TransactionScope however, as I understand it, enlists any service that is "transaction aware" within it's scope and creates a transation for it, any subsequent services will also join that transation unless specifically told not to and services that use other databases TransactionScope will escalate it to a distributed Transaction.

Is there any added overhead to TransactionScope that would preclude it from being used heavily in a high performance multi-user system? Can I wrap all of my data access code within a TransactionScope object and not have to worry about locking or slow performance?

Comment: In almost all cases, SQL execution is the most time consuming routine, and that's why TransactionScope overhead is negligible.

Comment: SQL Server will not automatically create a transaction for one batch you send to the server. Instead it will run each statement in isolation. Meaning that if you issue two delete statements together, and the second one fails, all the changes done (temporarily) by the second one up until it failed will be "rolled back", whereas the first delete command will persist.

Comment: See this article as well: http://morten.bravonet.no/post/2012/02/04/Performance-impact-using-transactionscope.aspx

Comment: SQL Server seems to avoid promoting the transaction scope to a distributed transaction if you use the same connection string throughout, but when I forced it to be different, I got an error that said that the distributed transaction manager (MSDTC) was disabled.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the performance aspect at all. Once you've said you need to manage transaction scope for data integrity, you just signed up to whatever is required, which probably includes locks being in place for the lifetime of the scope. Locking and releasing to get a meaningful transaction is the real cost.

Comment: So can I safely use TransactionScope for EVERY database interaction? One concern I have is that I should just execute single SqlCommands without a TransactionScope defined but if I need a batch of SqlCommands with a rollback if any fail then I need to use a TransactionScope specifically.